# Monic associates of Polynomials over Integral Domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain, polynomial-rings

For a field $F$, a nonzero polynomial $f \in F[x]$ has exactly one monic associate. Show that for other polynomial rings $R[x]$ this is not necessarily true, even if $R$ is an integral domain.

My attempt:

If $R$ is an integral domain, the only non-zero divisor in $R$ is zero. Hence $\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain.

**edit: I am using $\mathbb{Z}$ as my integral domain example. Is there any other polynomial rings that are integral domains that might be easier?**

pf. Suppose $h$ is a nonzero polynomial such that $h \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then $h$ = a<sub>n</sub>x<sup>n</sup> + ... + a<sub>1</sub>x + a<sub>0</sub> $\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that one of the a<sub>i</sub> $\neq$ 0. Since the units in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are either 1 or -1,

This is where I am stuck. I do not know what to conclude from this last statement. Would highly appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Consider any constant polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ that is not a unit. Then there is no monic polynomial associate to it, since the monic polynomial of degree 0 is associate to the units.

Comment: Your "attempt" starts out with the assumption that $R$ is an integral domain (which seems a good place to start), but then you say "Hence $\mathbb Z$ is an integral domain."  While $\mathbb Z$ certainly is an integral domain, this is unrelated to knowing that $R$ also is.  Moreover in $\mathbb Z[x]$, what happens is that non-monic polynomials have a monic associate only if the leading coefficient is $-1$.  But if polynomial $p(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$ has a monic associate, that monic associate is unique.

Comment: @hardmath So for $\mathbb{Z}$, although $\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain, a nonzero polynomial h $\in F[x]$ has exactly one monic associate? If that's the case, is there another polynomial ring that's an integral domain that might be easier?

Comment: @yagayeet:  Again you seem to be jumping from $\mathbb Z[x]$ to some unrelated polynomial ring $F[x]$.  My point was that a polynomial with leading coefficient not $\pm 1$ like $2x+3 \in \mathbb Z[x]$ has *no* monic associate in $\mathbb Z[x]$, and thus it is false that every polynomial has exactly one monic associate.

Comment: @hardmath I'm sorry, I meant to write $h \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

As your opening paragraph states, in a ring of (univariate) polynomials over a field $F$, say $F[x]$, each nonzero polynomial $p(x)$ has exactly one monic associate (a multiple $cp(x)$ where $c$ is a unit in $F[x]$, in this case a nonzero element of $F$).

In a similar polynomial ring $R[x]$ over an arbitrary integral domain $R$ this is no longer true, not because a nonzero polynomial $p(x)$ could have more than one monic associate but because it may have *no* monic associate at all.

The situation with integral domain $\mathbb Z$ illustrates this.  Consider a nonzero first degree polynomial, say $p(x) = mx + b$ with $m,b \in \mathbb Z$.  What would it mean for a polynomial to be a monic associate of $p(x)$?  We would need to find a unit in $\mathbb Z[x]$ such that multiplying it by $p(x)$ gives us the desired monic associate.

But the only units in $\mathbb Z[x]$ are $\pm 1$.  So $p(x)$ has a monic associate only if $m=\pm 1$, so the sought polynomial *without* a monic associate could be as simple as $p(x) = 2x$.

What is true for integral domain $R$ is that when a polynomial $p(x) \in R[x]$ *has* a monic associate, it has exactly one monic associate (uniqueness).  This follows (with perhaps a little thought) from observing that the units of $R[x]$ are precisely the units of $R$ (assuming the usual inclusion in $R[x]$).  It then happens that a polynomial $p(x) \in R[x]$ has a monic associate if and only if the leading coefficient of $p(x)$ is a unit of $R$.  Of course this happens for *all* nonzero polynomials in $R[x]$ only when $R$ is a field (so that all nonzero leading coefficients are units).  We've now circled back to the beginning of your problem's setup.